# ASP.NET Core Blazor Server additional security scenarios

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I create new clean Blazor ServerSide app (.Net 5) and i did every thing in this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0, But when i tried to run project i get this error when project start :

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultAuthenticateScheme found

Did anyone test this scenario and make it work?

My code :

App.razor

```
@inject TokenProvider TokenProvider
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public InitialApplicationState InitialState { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TokenProvider.AccessToken = InitialState.AccessToken;
        TokenProvider.RefreshToken = InitialState.RefreshToken;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

_Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace BlazorServerSaveToken.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlazorServerSaveToken</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorServerSaveToken.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
@{
    var tokens = new InitialApplicationState
    {
        AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
        RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
    };
}
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState="tokens" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Startup.cs

```
using BlazorServerSaveToken.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;

namespace BlazorServerSaveToken
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization(
                    new AuthorizeAttribute
                    {
                        AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                    });
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make *what* work? The page you linked to talks about two different things, in both cases offering generic advice, not specific implementations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's not different things, This senario is about save a JWT and refersh token in blazor to send it back to API with every request